# Store OAuth 2 token from Google API for future requests

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I can authorize and make authorized requests to Google API using the documentation and sample code (from [Authorizing and Making Authorized Requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests)):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Loads the client library and the auth2 library together for efficiency.
        // Loading the auth2 library is optional here since `gapi.client.init` function will load
        // it if not already loaded. Loading it upfront can save one network request.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function initClient() {
        // Initialize the client with API key and People API, and initialize OAuth with an
        // OAuth 2.0 client ID and scopes (space delimited string) to request access.
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
            clientId: 'YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'profile'
        }).then(function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
    }

    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        // When signin status changes, this function is called.
        // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
        if (isSignedIn) {
        makeApiCall();
        }
    }

    function handleSignInClick(event) {
        // Ideally the button should only show up after gapi.client.init finishes, so that this
        // handler won't be called before OAuth is initialized.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }

    function handleSignOutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    }

    function makeApiCall() {
        // Make an API call to the People API, and print the user's given name.
        gapi.client.people.people.get({
        'resourceName': 'people/me',
        'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
        }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Hello, ' + response.result.names[0].givenName);
        }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
    onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign In</button>
    <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign Out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I can only make requests as long as the session is alive. What I want is to store the token in a database and then make requests using this token.

Ultimately, I want to have a user settings page where the user can give consent to the app (i.e. link/unlink Google API), so they always can see if they have authorized and when the access token has to be renewed. I want it to behave similar to when users usually can link/unlink "Sign in with Facebook/Google/GitHub" in their account settings.

But I don't in the Google API documentation how to retrieve the token and how to make requests based on the shortlived token.

How do I accomplish this? Are there any examples of doing this in the Google API documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The token you are seeing is an access token. Access tokens are short lived tokens that give you access to a users data.   What you need is a refresh token which will give you the ability to request a new access token when ever the access token you have expires (After an hour).

You can not use refresh tokens with client sided applications.  You will need to switch to a server sided solution like node.js, php, or python for example.

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mention a token I'm seeing, but I don't see any tokens at all. I just receive a popup to give consent to authorize with my Google account and then it seems the token is saved in `gapi.client`. I can at least provide requests to the platform by calling `gapi.client`, but I never provide any access token with my requests

Comment: You wont see it its built into the Google api javascript client library.  It handles all of this for you.   This library and language does not have the ability to do what you are asking.  You need to switch to something server sided.